# loading panel with %symbol

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bootstrap-4

[image: Loading panel]

I want to display a loading panel with percentage symbol. please share your suggestion. I searched but did not get with %age . Most of the links showing spinner to use. But I need panel with % symbol.

is there any possible to display the loading panel with %age.

Comment: Provide code/research/material you have tried prior to asking this question.

Comment: do you want a page loading progress bar of some sort? like [pace.js](https://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/)?

Comment: I don't want progress bar alone. what ever it is loading panel (spinner,loader anything with % symbol i need to display

Comment: How are you getting your %age loaded?

Comment: I am blank. is there any possiblity get the % along with the loading panel

Comment: You can achieve this with [`ui.bootstrap` Progressbar](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#progressbar)

Answer (score 0):

Without any proper code to showcase your problem I can only recommend default BS4 loading bar with label template:

```
<div class="progress">
 <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="25" a 
             ria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">labelHere</div>
</div>
```

You will want the static 'labelHere' replaced with AngularJS binding like:

```
{{myAgePercentage}}%
```

This assumes you are calculating percentage somewhere in your AngularJS code.

More general information on BS4 progress component here:
[BS4 Progress](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/progress/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use bootstrap progress bars as follows -

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
  aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
    40% <!-- {{$scope.progressVar + ' &#37;'}} -->
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: like this]
**[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp)**'s more for your reference.

Comment: Here, you are hot coding % value .. is there any possible to increase that progress bar start

Comment: Referring this - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/progressLinear may help you